# How to copy a file from host to container using docker-py (docker SDK)

Tags: python, docker, docker-container, dockerpy

I know, there is possible way how to copy file bidirectionally between host and docker container using `docker cp` and also it is possible to obtain file from running container using docker-py. But I am not able to figure out how (or if it is even possible) copy file from host to running container using docker-py. 
Do you guys have any experiences with such kind of problem? Is it possible to do or I have to execute command using python `os.system`. I would like to avoid this solution.

Comment: You can do interesting things with `put_archive`. https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.put_archive

Comment: Thank you, I missed this option in SDK, I was aimed on copy. I am going to try it

Comment: Any update here? I'm trying to copy files on local machine into docker container

Comment: check out the answers here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59743346/6420513

Answer (score 27):

Something like this should work:

```
import os
import tarfile
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

def copy_to(src, dst):
    name, dst = dst.split(':')
    container = client.containers.get(name)

    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(src))
    srcname = os.path.basename(src)
    tar = tarfile.open(src + '.tar', mode='w')
    try:
        tar.add(srcname)
    finally:
        tar.close()

    data = open(src + '.tar', 'rb').read()
    container.put_archive(os.path.dirname(dst), data)
```

And then use it like:

```
copy_to('/local/foo.txt', 'my-container:/tmp/foo.txt')
```

Comment: How to extract the archive in container, after put_archive ?

Comment: What is the file name after put_archive in container ?

Comment: @MalarKandasamy seems like put_archive is extracting it in dst

Answer (score 7):

Code snippet using memory BytesIO:

```
def copy_to_container(container: 'Container', src: str, dst_dir: str):
    """ src shall be an absolute path """
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=stream, mode='w|') as tar, open(src, 'rb') as f:
        info = tar.gettarinfo(fileobj=f)
        info.name = os.path.basename(src)
        tar.addfile(info, f)

    container.put_archive(dst_dir, stream.getvalue())
```

Comment: Nice! This can be simplified a bit by executing `tar.add(src, arcname=os.path.basename(src))` in the with block instead of opening the file, creating the tarinfo and adding the file object.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import tarfile
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

def copy_to(src, dst):
    name, dst = dst.split(':')
    container = client.containers.get(name)

    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(src))
    srcname = os.path.basename(src)
    tar = tarfile.open(srcname + '.tar', mode='w')
    obj=os.walk(srcname)
    for items in obj:
        for files in items[2]:
            if files[-4::] == ".csv" :
                abs_path = items[0] + "/" + files
                tar.add(abs_path)

    tar.close()
    data = open(srcname + '.tar', 'rb')
    container.put_archive(dst, data)
    data.close()

copy_to('source_directory', 'container_name:destination_directory')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).